# Не могу понять почему не решается на 100%

Tags: python, список

> ### Два минимума
>
> Найдите два различных наименьших элемента в числовой последовательности.
>
> **Входные данные**
>
> В первой строке находится количество элементов `n` (`3 ≤ n ≤ 1000`) последовательности. Далее заданы `n` чисел, каждое из которых не превышает `2 * 109` по абсолютному значению.
>
> **Выходные данные**
>
> Выведите в возрастающем порядке два различных наименьших элемента последовательности. Известно, что они всегда существуют.

Решаю на Python, но не пойму что не так (31%)

код:

```
b = int(input())
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
a = list(set(a))
a.sort()
print(a[0], a[1])
```

пробовал также:

```
b = int(input())
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(min(a), end = ' ')
m = min(a)
while m in a:
    a.remove(min(a))
print(min(a))
```

но результат не меняется.
Вопрос как сделать чтобы было 100%

Comment: а сюда привести вопрос никак нельзя было?

Comment: ссылка на проверяющию систему:https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/5059

Answer (score 1, accepted):

по каким-то причинам вход иногда бывает в две строки поэтому результат не верен. Данный код может принимать вход в несколько строк

```
n = int(input())
arr = []
while len(arr) < n:
    arr += map(int, input().split())

sort = sorted(set(arr))
print(*sort[:2])
```

Comment: Спасибо. Задача решена. Я и подумать не мог про две и больше строк.

Comment: @Andrey я тоже не мог понять почему не работает. Я просто перешёл в обсуждение и там говорилось об этом

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял украинский

```
n = int(input())
arr = sorted(list(map(int, input().split())))

a1 = arr[0]
a2 = a1

for i in arr:
    if i != a1:
        a2 = i
        break

print(a1, a2)
```

можно обойтись без сортировки и сделать за O(2n):

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

a1 = min(arr)
a2 = None

for i in arr:
    if i != a1 and (a2 is None or i < a2):
        a2 = i

print(a1, a2)
```

**P.S.**

есть мысли почему может не проходить текст

1. возможно в последовательности передаются числа с плавающей запятой, тогда `int` надо поменять на `float`

   ```
    arr = list(map(float, input().split()))
   ```
2. в последовательности указывается больше чисел, чем указано в первом параметре и тогда надо отрезать лишнее:

   ```
    n = int(input())
    arr = list(map(int, input().split()))[:n]
   ```

Comment: мне кажется что во втором примере `list(...)` лучше заменить на `set(...)`

Comment: я зарегистрировался на сайте и протестировал.У вас и у автора не все тесты проходятся из-за неправильного результата

Comment: @Danis, так второй пример как раз чтобы не использовать `set` и получить O(n), на счет не все тесты проходит - надо смотреть в чем дело, по времени не проходит или по результатам, в задаче говорится, что решение есть (т.е. есть 2 разных значения в списке) - и честно говоря я не вижу пока ошибки, единственное что приходит в голову - могут передаваться и нецелые числа, тогда это вопрос к составителям, что не оговорили - а в моем решении просто поменять int на float

Comment: В том и вопрос почему результат не правильный?

Comment: @Andrey, я в своем ответе написал 2 возможных варианта почему неправильные решения - или `float` или передают последовательности длиннее, чем указанный выше размер последовательности

Comment: если бы передавали `float` то появилась бы ошибка т.к. строку с точкой нельзя превратить в число

Comment: вот что выдаёт проверяющая система на ваш код https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYovg.jpg

Comment: зашёл в обсуждение и увидел следующее `Неужели так трудно в условии задачи написать,что числа будут заданы в НЕСКОЛЬКИХ СТРОКАХ? Я считаю,что ВХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ должны быть описаны как можно ПОДРОБНЕЕ.Чтобы программист НЕ ГАДАЛ как бабка на кофейной гуще.`

Comment: @Danis, я проверил - нормально вводятся числа с плавающей запятой, парсятся, конвертируются и заносятся в список, и с запятой и в экспоненциальном виде и с запятой в экспоненциальном виде - в общем как угодно пиши, все корректно распознается